# How to configure App Engine to show this webpage for the webapp only to the administrator?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

[This webpage](http://1.augmented-clock-415.appspot.com) appeared when I deployed my app on the App Engine and it seems anyone can access it and send messages to all the Android devices registered with my webapp. Although, there is an option to authenticate users before posting messages but I don't want even the users of my app to post messages to the registered devices. Is there a way to make this page accessible only to the app administrator?

Thanks in anticipation for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a feature available in App Engine console to provide Admin only pages. This feature allows you to define certain URLs/pages that will require an Administrator of your application to login. App Engine does all the heavy lifting for you and you would not really need to change your code too.

Check out the documentation : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Administration_console_custom_pages

Once you configure it, the pages will appear inside of the App Engine console.

Comment: This approach seems to be available only for Python environment. Is there an analogous method for Java handlers?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using webapp2 handlers to output this page, and storing the current username in a session variable, here is what you can do to perform this check just before writing this page on the response stream:

```
class Settings(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('settings.html')
        user=self.session['user']
        if user=='admin': #validate your admin user here.
            self.response.write( template.render(values) )
        else:
            self.redirect('/404') #or anything of your choosing
```

BaseHandler is a special class I've derived from webapp2.RequestHandler and included session handling features in it. Read my complete [artcile](http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/how-to-handle-sessions-in-google-app-engine/) to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks Prahlad! I am completely new to web development and the application that I have just deployed is my first project on App Engine by following Google's tutorial for an Android app with an App-Engine backend using Google's plugin for eclipse.

Where should I incorporate your class and how should I use it to control the display of this webpage? Currently, this webpage is appearing automatically after I deployed my app on the App Engine.